# How to alias/set display name for odata metadata xml document (v4)

Tags: excel, odata

Following is a sample of the metadata that is returned by my odata endpoint.  I am using the endpoint w/ Microsoft Excel Power Query.  All is working OK, except that I want to change the displayed name of "MyTable" below to something else, like say "My Cool Table".

I have tried adding annotations, but anytime I add annotations, Excel throws a cryptic error that says my metadata is invalid.

The question is, given the OData XML metadata below, what do I need to add so that the name of the table that is displayed is "My Cool Table" instead of "MyTable".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<edmx:Edmx xmlns:edmx="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx" Version="4.0">
    <edmx:DataServices xmlns:m="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/metadata" m:MaxDataServiceVersion="4.0" m:DataServiceVersion="4.0">
        <Schema xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm" Namespace="MyOData">
            <EntityType Name="MyTable">
                <Key>
                    <PropertyRef Name="myid" />
                </Key>
                <Property Name="myid" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" />
                <Property Name="Anotherfield" Type="Edm.String" />
            </EntityType>
            <EntityContainer Name="DefaultContainer">
                <EntitySet Name="MyTable" EntityType="MyOData.MyTable" />
            </EntityContainer>
        </Schema>
    </edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution to your need ? I'm looking for something similar: set a display name on the object's properties so when used in excel, we get nicely formatted column names rather than the more "programmer-friendly" json names!

Comment: Nope never did find a solution, sorry.  In general there were some fairly janky things in how OData was implemented, including, but not limited to the lack of consistent documentation.